# Context-insensitive completion popup in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm experimenting with the transition from Vim to Emacs, and one of Vim's features that I really miss is the context-insensitve completion popup (`CTRL-n` and `CTRL-p`). For example, in the buffer below, if I were to type `he` then `CTRL-n`, I would get a popup:

[image: vim context insensitive completion menu]

How can I get a similar context-insensitive completion menu in Emacs?

Note: I specifically want context-insensitive because it's often helpful to make references across different contexts (for example, reference a Python class from Restructured Text documentation) — something context-sensitive "omnicomplete" doesn't do.

Additionally, I know that `M-/` will trigger auto-completion, but it only cycles through matches; I want a popup list showing matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Auto Complete Mode](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) should do what you're looking for.

It's generally not triggered by a hotkey, but something like:

```
(setq ac-auto-start nil)
(global-set-key "\M-/" 'auto-complete)
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Awesome! And is there any way I can remap `C-n` and `C-p` to select the next/previous autocomplete item? (instead of using up arrow and down arrow)?

Comment: `(define-key ac-complete-mode-map "\C-n" 'ac-next)

(define-key ac-complete-mode-map "\C-p" 'ac-previous)`

Comment: I think the trigger key way is much better than the automatic showing way, today I spent hours trying to make the dropdown menu automatically show when I types, but failed, it always spent more about 2 seconds showing. But the trigger key is much better. Thank you. @tdresser

Answer (score 1):

Auto Complete Mode shows a dropdown menu with matches: http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Basic_Usage

You can install it via the Marmalade repository: http://marmalade-repo.org/, follow the instructions to setup Marmalade, then M-x package-install auto-complete. You'll have to activate auto-complete-mode, then while typing anything it will show you matches (you can also force it by pressing TAB, by default).